# Django AWS Eslastic Beanktalk not deploying - Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm following this tutorial:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

I'm on Step 6. I already created my AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python Application and now I want to link it to my Django application.

This is my directory:

```
~/Documents/myapp
myapp manage.py requirements.txt .ebextensions .elasticbeanstalk .git .gitignore
```

Inside my .ebextensions is myapp.config:

```
container_commands:
    01_syncdb:    
        command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
        leader_only: true

option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
        option_name: WSGIPath
        value: myapp/wsgi.py
    - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
        value: myapp.settings
    - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
        value: myUsersSecretKey
    - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        value: myUsersAcessKey
```

Inside

```
~/Documents/myapp/myapp
```

is my settings.py, views.py etc. I made the database in my settings.py to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

as it said in the tutorial. I then did

```
git add .
git commit -m "eb configuration"
git aws.push
```

it said that the environment update initiated successfully. After I waited for the status to be ready, I went to the URL and it is still the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python success page and is not my django application. Any idea why?

Edit: I then tried following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJoOnKiSYws (pause at 7:44)

and changed my config file to:

```
container_commands:
    01_syncdb:    
        command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
        leader_only: true

option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
        option_name: WSGIPath
        value: myapp/wsgi.py
    - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
        value: myapp.settings
    - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        option_name: EC2KeyName
        value: myKeyPairName
```

and now when I refreshed the page after the status was ready, it gave an internal server error saying:

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the sever administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time and error occured, and anything you might have done that may have acused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

EDIT 2:

Is my wsgi.py file supposed to look a certain way when dealing with AWS elastic beanstalk? I left the wsgi.py file how it was when it was first created because the tutorial did as well. This is my wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ayflare.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Instead of `git aws.push` do you mean `git push aws`?

Comment: @AndrewJohnson hm no, in the tutorial, it says "git aws.push"

Comment: Ok, it looks like they modify git to add that command. As long as it works for you, then it is not the problem at hand.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson does my wsgi.py file supposed to look a certain way? I left the file how it normally is when it is first created because the tutorial did as well.

Comment: My first thought was that your local files weren't getting synced with AWS. Since this is using beanstalk I am not sure how that works or how to check it. It is a proprietary extension to git, and I am not familiar with that part of AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of things here,

- You might want to try using "python manage.py syncdb --noinput" in
  the config instead of using "django-admin.py". I seem to remember
  encountering some issues until I switched to "python manage.py".
- Another thing that might be worthwhile doing is enabling DEBUG in
  your django settings file to see if you can get a more detailed error
  message about the issue.
- Sometimes, if you mess up the deployment is EB, rebuilding the
  environment can help smooth out issues once you sort them in your
  code/config files. You can do this in the Elastic Beanstalk page in
  the AWS Management Console.
- Your first myapp.config file looks correct. The updated one that you got from the youtube video doesn't seem correct if you are following the official Amazon Docs.